# Bluetooth not working ASUS TUF GAMING B550-PLUS (WiFi) 21.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 21.04

The motherboard should have a bluetooth module, but when I open the Bluetooth settings it says: No Bluetooth found. Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth.

I've also tried plugging in a Bluetooth USB dongle and then it says: Bluetooth Turned Off Turn on to connect devices and receive file transfers. But when I turn it on nothing happens.

Comment: did you solve it?